# Can a fourth point(vertex) be on the circumference of a circumcircle formed by 3 points in Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangulation

I understand that in Delaunay triangulation that no points should be placed inside any of the  circumcircles , but is a fourth point allowed to be on the circumference of the circle other than the 3 original points which formed the circle. If it is not allowed then how can we perform Delaunay triangulation on the four vertices of a square because the fourth vertex always falls on the circumference of the circumcircle.

Comment: tThe short answer is "yes" precisely for the kind of example you propose. In "practical terms" the answer is that it won't happen, or, rather, will happen with zero probability if the problem is random in any reasonable sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Delaunay diagram is the dual of the Voronoi diagram.

The Delaunay diagram is a triangulation iff there are no four cocircular points.

When there are four or more cocircular points, the corresponding Delaunay face can be triangulated arbitrarily.